# Print out datetime as DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: python, datetime

I'm making a program that will print out a set of savings for tomorrow only, and i wanted to specify what date tomorrow was, which i did like this:

```
Tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Which gives the outpu:

```
2016-04-11
```

as you can see, it does give tomorrows date like planned, except it does it in the YYYY-MM-DD format, which is my issue. is there a way to have tomorrows date printed in the DD-MM-YYYY format?
Cheers

Comment: why is this being downvoted?

Comment: @n1c9 because the answer is easily found by a google search or looking at the `datetime` docs.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, Matt.  I have been searching using google and have not found how to do this until now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Tomorrow.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` should sort you. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, It worked a charm :). I tried that before, but I'm dumb and didn't set it out right, so it didn't affect it at all xD Thanks very much!

Comment: Would you please click the green check as well?

Comment: Done :). I had to wait for it to let me first :)

Answer (score -3):

Here is my answer:

```
dt = "9'/30'/2017  16:40:09"           # assume dt is the datetime variable
date, space, time = dt.partition(' ')  # use dt.partition to separate date and time by space
mm, slash, str = date.partition('/')   # use date.partition to separate mm and str by slash, mm is found
dd, slash, yyyy = str.partition('/')   # use str.partition to separate dd and yyyy by slash, dd and yyyy are found
new_date = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy  # set new_date in any desired format 
# new_date = 30/9/2017
```

Comment: I ran this code and it didn't print the date out as dd/mm/yyyy.